# Website is not opening after reload

Tags: wordpress, reload

I am working with `example.com`I am getting problem while reload. website opens at first time but website is not opening after reload.

Comment: try reloading after clearing your browser & wordpress cache on server.

Comment: You can also try after disabling all plugins & then re-enable one by one to check if any plugin is causing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try after disabling all plugins & then re-enable one by one to check if any plugin is causing problem.

Also, enable debug mode in wordpress:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible reasons for this from errors to memory limit or malware.
Try to turn on debug mode in wp-config.php like

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);
error_reporting(1);
ini_set("display_errors","on");
```

And try to browse error log files to find solution

Comment: Hello Apul & Asgu both I have done debug reporting but nothing is reported in error log file